# What is the relationship between an nginx ingress controller and a cloud load balancer?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I deploy an `nginx ingress controller` to my cluster. This provisions a load balancer in my cloud provider (assume AWS or GCE). However, all traffic inside the cluster is routed by the controller based on my ingress rules and annotations.

What is then the purpose of having a load balancer in the cloud sit in front of this controller? It seems like the controller is doing the actual load balancing anyway?

I would like to understand how to have it so that the cloud load balancer is actually routing traffic towards machines inside the cluster while still following all my `nginx` configurations/annotations or even if that is possible/makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a High Availability (HA) Cluster with multiple masters, a Load Balancer is a easy and practical way to "enter" in your Kubernetes cluster, as your applications are supposed to be usable by your users (who are on a different net from your cluster).
So you need to have an entry point to your K8S cluster.

A LB is an easy configurable entrypoint.

Take a look at this picture as example:
[image]

Your API servers are load balanced. A call from outside your cluster will pass through the LB and will be manager by a API server. Only one master (the elected one) will be responsible to persist the status of the cluster in the etcd database.

When you have `ingress controller` and `ingress rules`, in my opinion it's easier to configure and manage them inside K8S, instead of writing them in the LB configuration file (and reload the configuration on each modification).

I suggest you to take a look at https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way and make the exercise inside it. It's a good way to understand the flow.

Answer (score 1):

In ingress controller is a "controller", which in kubernetes terms is a software loop that listens for changes to declarative configuration (the Ingress resource) and to the relevant "state of the cluster", compares the two, and then "reconciles" the state of the cluster to declarative configuration.

In this case, the "state of the cluster" is a combination of:

- an nginx configuration file generated by the controller, in use by the pods in the cluster running nginx
- the configuration at the cloud provider that instructs the provider's edge traffic infrastructure to deliver certain externally-delivered traffic meeting certain criteria to the nginx pods in your cluster.

So when you update an Ingress resource, the controller notices the change, creates a new nginx configuration file, updates and restarts the pods running nginx.

In terms of the physical architecture- it is not really accurate to visualize things as "inside" your cluster vs "outside", or "your cluster" and "the cloud." Everything customer visible is an abstraction.

In GCP, there are several layers of packet and traffic management underneath the customer-visible VMs, load balancers and managed clusters.

External traffic destined for ingress passes through several logical control points in Google's infrastructure, the details of which you have no visibility into, before it gets to "your" cluster.